# If a set is $F_\sigma$ and is of first category then it is a countable union of closed nowhere dense sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

We say a set is $F_\sigma$ if it is a countable union of closed sets. We say a set is of first category if it is a countable union of nowhere dense sets.

The question is, if a set of $F_\sigma$ and of first category, is it true that this set is a countable union of closed nowhere dense sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an $F_\sigma$ set of the first category is the union of countably many closed nowhere dense sets.

Since an $F_\sigma$ set of the first category is the union of countably many closed sets of the first category, it will suffice to show that a closed set of the first category is the union of countably many closed nowhere dense sets. Well, a closed set of the first category is the union of countably many nowhere dense sets, and it is also the union of the closures of those nowhere dense sets, and the closure of a nowhere dense set is a closed nowhere dense set, Q.E.D.

Actually, a closed set of the first category (in a Baire space) is nowhere dense; so there is a shorter proof, if you're working with a Baire space.

Comment: If a set $A$ is $F_\sigma$ and is of first category, then it is a countable union of closed nowhere dense sets. In this case, is $A$ closed? The closure of an infinite union may not be equal to the infinite union of closures right?

Comment: Right, an $F_\sigma$ set of first category is not necessarily closed. Any countable subset of $\mathbb R$ is an $F_\sigma$ set of first category, but a countable set of real numbers is not necessarily closed, for example, the set $\mathbb Q$ of all rational numbers.